# Finding Elliptic Curves with Provably Different Number of Points

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Is there a way to find $k$ elliptic curves over $F_q$, all with *provably* different number of points?

And doing so without counting the number of points on the curves.

For really small $k$ (2,3) I know some examples of families of curves that has different number of points for different members. But I don't know of a family where this can be achieve for a large k.

I also know that having different j-invariant doesn't ensure different number of points. But maybe there is another way to use the j-invariant here?